# Rename/Move branch folder with different case

Tags: git

We had a slight mismatch in our team, and we accidentally named our folders the same thing.. but with a different case. So we now have `Feature/FeatureName` and `feature/featureName`. We want to use camel casing for our branches, so we want `feature/featureName`.

I tried to move `Feature` into an `oldFeatures` branch by doing:

```
git mv Feature oldFeature
```

but I got a:

> fatal: Invalid branch name: 'Feature'

Problem is this: When the user with `Feature` tries to do:

```
git branch -b feature/newestFeature
git add .
git commit -m "Feature added"
git push -u origin feature/newestFeature
```

He will get this error:

> fatal: feature/newestFeature cannot be resolved to branch.

When that same user branches into an already existing branch with lowercase (which he did not create), the same issue happens when trying to push back into that same branch.

What's the best option here? I can't move the `Feature` branch/folder away, I can't use the `feature` branch/folder because it says "cannot be resolved to branch", and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up deleting all the remote branches, removing the local copy of the Git folder, then cloned a brand spanking new one. Works fine now.